# (GPO) Set AD-User as local admin on all PCs in specific OU

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, organizational-unit

In my AD I have these two OU's: **OU PC and OU User**. There are a few users in the OU "Users" and several machines in the OU "PC".
I now need to write a GPO for one of these users which will automatically add him to the "local administrator group" on all of these machines - which either already are in that OU "PC", or will be added in the future.
Of course I could set him as a local admin manually on all of these PC's, but I need it to do that automatically.

Is there an option or a way to do that using a GPO?

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

You add local admins with **Restricted Groups**, which is in *Computer Configuration*. Therefore you can by definition add this GPO for the OU containing the computers you want it to affect.

1. Add a new Group Object in your AD, e.g. `DOMAIN\Local Admins` Its container is not relevant.
2. Add a new GPO "Local Admins" and link it to the `OU=PC`.
3. In **Computer Configuration** > **Policies** > **Windows Settings** > **Security Settings** > **Restricted Groups**, Add Group `DOMAIN\Local Admins`
4. Add to *This group is a member of* groups: `Administrators` & `Remote Desktop Users`.

If you use different language versions of Windows the administrative [group names can be different](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/da93e3b4-7837-47e8-a781-f1f9bfbed89f/how-to-configure-restricted-groups-the-right-way-with-different-client-computer-languages). In multilingual environments you can refer to these [generic groups](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems) by their *security identifiers* (SIDs):

- `S-1-5-32-544` for `Administrators`
- `S-1-5-32-555` for `BUILTIN\Remote Desktop Users`

Comment: Thank you! I have a question: If I add the Group "Local Admins" to the Group "Administrators", dosen't the members of the group "Local Admins" then become domain administrators? They are only meant to have the local administrator rights on all machines that are in the OU "PC" and not on a single other PC in the domain.

Comment: The _Restricted Groups_ exists exactly to prevent that! You don't add the group into `Administrators` AD group. The GPO adds the group to the builtin `Administrators` group on **every single computer the GPO is applied to**. Then, you can add more `Local Admins` to that group and they will have administrative rights on target computers without waiting for the [Group Policy refresh interval](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940895.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Buttons.

You can either use Group Policy Preferences to change the membership of local groups or you can use the restricted groups option to adjust the membership of local groups. The two links below will give you some guidance.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn581922(v=ws.11).aspx

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20402.active-directory-group-policy-restricted-groups.aspx